# Why connection to postgres from nodejs is not working?

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, roles

I have back-end created in nodejs hosted on Debian server using postgres 14.
the Nodejs listenning on port 5000, and when I try to connect to postgres using port 5432, I am getting the following reponse from Postman:
"Password is invalid".
I was trying the postgres role, and to create a new role, and problem is the same.
I was installing postgres on my Windows 10 computer, and all works fine in my localhost, but on the remote server not.
My Nodejs back-end, and postgres are on the same computer, but each role I've tryed won't connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

There is pg_hba.conf in /etc/postgres/14 on your server you have to add:

host username database 0.0.0.0/0 md5

This would allow connection to database from any host to username using password authentication.

Also there is a pg.conf or postgres conf
There is line allow_connections the value should be '*'

allow_connections='*'

This would generally allow connections to postgres running on that server

Guide https://coderwall.com/p/cr2a1a/allowing-remote-connections-to-your-postgresql-vps-installation

don’t forget you have to reload postgres after config change:

systemctl reload postgres

Comment: I was trying this, but postman gives the same error. I was trying:
systemctl restart postgresql

Comment: Try something like https://dbeaver.io/

Comment: Btw you can check that out https://supabase.com/ postgres without stress

Comment: Thank you. I succeeded. There was postgresql 11 and postgresql 14. I had removed all postgresql packages, installed postgresql-14, created all roles with passwords, set encryption to scram-sha-256, and all works fine.